# Website scraping with python 2.7 and beautifulsoup 4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have stuck at one point while scraping website "http://www.queensbronxba.com/directory/" with beautifulsoup. I'm almost done with scraping and I left only company name from the list which is found in paragraph tag. The problem is that there are more paragraph tags in the same div but I only need the first one as it gives the company name. So I need first paragraph on following div's also not just at first one. This is the code I used to srcape:

```
page = requests.get("http://www.queensbronxba.com/directory/")  
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')  
company = soup.find(class_="boardMemberWrap")  
contact = company.find_all(class_="boardMember")  
info = contact[0]
print(info.prettify())

name_tags = company.select("h4")  
names = [nt.get_text() for nt in company_tags]  
names

company_tags = company.select("p")  #here I need help to get only first paragraphs of following div containers  
companies = [ct.get_text() for ct in company_tags]  
companies

phone_tags = company.select('a[href^="tel"]')  
phones = [pt.get_text() for pt in phone_tags]  
phones

email_tags = company.select('a[href^="mailto"]')  
emails = [et.get_text() for et in email_tags]  
emails
```

Comment: Be specific in what is your problem. Now what are you stuck with?

Comment: There is comment at company_tags which says where I need help.

Comment: You should describe the problem outside of your code in your question, so it's clearly stated. If you only want one paragraph out of all the text you are getting, parse the text, maybe split the text by `\n`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("http://www.queensbronxba.com/directory/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')  
company = soup.find(class_="boardMemberWrap")  
contact = company.findAll(class_="boardMemberInfo")
info = contact[0]
print(info.prettify())


name_tags = company.select("h4")
names = [nt.get_text() for nt in name_tags]
print(names)


for name in company.findAll(class_="boardMember"):
    for n in name.findAll('p')[:1]:
    print(n.text)


phone_tags = company.select('a[href^="tel"]')  
phones = [pt.get_text() for pt in phone_tags]  
print(phones)


email_tags = company.select('a[href^="mailto"]')  
emails = [et.get_text() for et in email_tags]  
print(emails)
```